# Compare two excel workbooks: VBA arrays not equal

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two excelworkbooks and list the differences in this workbook.

I am getting error "Type Mismatched" in the below line:

```
If varSheetA <> varSheetB Then
```

**Code:**

```
Sub compareworkb()

    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Solution - Beginners template .xlsx")
    Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Template_Project Lead - Beginners.xlsx")

    For i = 1 To wbkA.Sheets.Count    
        Set varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets(wbkA.Sheets(i).Name)
        Set varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets(wbkB.Sheets(i).Name)

        strRangeToCheck = "A1:N100"

        Debug.Print Now
        varSheetA = varSheetA.Range(strRangeToCheck)
        varSheetB = varSheetB.Range(strRangeToCheck)
        Debug.Print Now
        For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
            For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)    
                If varSheetA <> varSheetB Then
                    wbkB.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + sh, 2) = "Mismatch Found"
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + sh, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Variables `varSheetA` and `varSheetA` contain 2-dimensional arrays (for ranges of more than 1 cell), you can't compare the whole arrays with `<>` operator. It's necessary to check each element of array within nested loops.

Comment: any suggestions how to modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through every element of the arrays, but then trying to compare the *entire arrays* each time, which cannot be done with `<>`. Instead, just add the index of the items you are trying to compare

```
For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2) 
    ' Note this change vvvvv                   vvvvvv
        If varSheetA(iRow,iCol) <> varSheetB(iRow,iCol) Then
            wbkB.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + sh, 2) = "Mismatch Found"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + sh, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow
```

---

Edit:

It looks like you've changed your mind about how to loop through the sheets, and forgotten to update the variable names. For instance you are trying to reference the sheet `ShName`, when you haven't defined `ShName`, and you are trying to write to row `7+sh` when you haven't defined `sh`! You also hadn't then declared `i` as a variable before using it to loop.

**Also, you are getting a type mismatch error *when there is a variable type mismatch in your worksheet*!** For instance if you have an error in one cell, and an integer in the corresponding cell on the other sheet, you can't compare these things using `<>`. In the below code, I've included a variable type check, see comments for details. The code also encompasses the previously mentioned corrections:

```
Sub compareworkb()
    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim mismatch As Boolean
    Set wbkA = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbkB = Workbooks("test2.xlsx")

    strRangeToCheck = "A1:N100" ' Define this once outside the loop, as it doesn't change
    For i = 1 To wbkA.Sheets.Count
        varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets(i).Range(strRangeToCheck)
        varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets(i).Range(strRangeToCheck)

        For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
            For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
                mismatch = False
                ' Check that cell values are the same variable type
                If VarType(varSheetA(iRow, iCol)) = VarType(varSheetB(iRow, iCol)) Then
                    ' If they are the same variable type, we can compare them!
                    If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) <> varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
                        mismatch = True
                    End If
                Else ' If they are not the same variable type, then it must be a mismatch                        
                    mismatch = True
                End If
                ' If mismatch found then note it / colour corresponding cell
                If mismatch Then
                    wbkB.Sheets(i).Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + i, 2) = "Mismatch Found"
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + i, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            Next iCol
        Next iRow
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: On this line If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) <> varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then

Comment: Did you start using sheet objects like I sugeested?

Comment: can you guide me how to use that

Comment: I have simply copy pasted the above code when I pressed F5 its still giving type mismatch error

Comment: on this line : -  If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) <> varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then

Comment: It is not running in loop just highlighting the difference of one sheet and giving this error

Comment: Please see second edit, I think the issue was trying to compare cells with different variable types

Comment: Its working now thank you so much. There are few more information which I want it should fetch like all the differences should be collated in a new workbook highlighting the old cell value and the new cell value and also it should tell what sort of difference it is like :- missing value, formula error etc. So I will be modifying the code accordingly in case I am stuck will open another thread. But for now thank you so much....

Comment: No problem, sounds like you've got some work to do! Yes do open another Q if you are stuck, happy coding!